# Ruby on rails: Bundler not installed when deploying using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy to a ubuntu server using capistrano and get the following error:

```
Executing "cd /home/useracc/www/releases/20130420101911 && bundle install --gemfile /home/useracc/www/releases/20130420101911/Gemfile --path /home/useracc/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["dev.website.com"]
    [dev.self-sale.com] executing command
 ** [out :: dev.website.com] ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
 ** [out :: dev.website.com] 
    command finished in 510ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/useracc/www/releases/20130420101911; true"
    servers: ["dev.website.com"]
    [dev.self-sale.com] executing command
    command finished in 613ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/selfsale/www/releases/20130420101911 && bundle install --gemfile /home/useracc/www/releases/20130420101911/Gemfile --path /home/useracc/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on dev.website.com
```

I've done some searching and found that some people have resolved this issue by putting require "bundler/capistrano" in their deploy.rb.

I've tried that but it's not made any difference.

I have also tried installing bundler on the server but get:

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371 directory.
```

I don't remember setting RVM up though, so this is a little confusing to me.

Does any one have any suggestions?

This is an old app btw, here is my gem list:

% bundle exec gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.14)
actionpack (2.3.14)
activerecord (2.3.14)
activeresource (2.3.14)
activesupport (2.3.14)
brightbox (2.3.9)
bundler (1.3.5)
capistrano (2.14.2)
highline (1.6.16)
hoe (3.5.2)
hpricot (0.8.2)
htmldoc (0.2.3)
json (1.7.7)
macaddr (1.6.1)
mysql (2.9.1)
net-scp (1.1.0)
net-sftp (2.1.1)
net-ssh (2.6.7)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
paginator (1.1.1)
rack (1.1.6)
rails (2.3.14)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (4.0.1)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
rmagick (2.13.1)
systemu (2.5.2)
uuid (2.0.2)
will_paginate (2.3.16)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is: You have bundler installed to a specific gemset, which is why it's only available when you are in your app's directory so try to install bundler to a global gemset.

`rvm gemset use global && gem install bundler`

Comment: Thanks @shrikant1712, in the end I needed to reinstall rvm as my local user rather root as I was getting permissions errors.